# Reality Composer where is?

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

try to do something with Reality Composer or Reality Composer Pro, apple says is on the Xcode 15, but I can't find it?? where should I look to open it?

Before they had a link on their web site but now how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is not available in the release version of Xcode 15 (or 15.1).  See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737727 for responses from a couple of Apple employees.  They suggest installing Xcode 14 or Xcode 15 beta 8.